# Angular 2 RC4 - Select ngModel delayed update

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a select control that will bind the value to an Object and on change I can get access to the selected object.

I know there has a been a lot of changes in the forms so not sure if this is a user error or bug or not possible.

Here is where I'm at so far: [Link to Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YKVv7nrZbtJ8HxwpTcjt)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
       <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
       <select (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selected">
          <option value=''></option>
          <option *ngFor="let d of data" [ngValue]="d">
             {{d.name}}
          </option>
       </select>
   `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  diagnostic;
  selected;
  data = [
     { id: 1 , name: 'query 1', filters: [
        { 'filter1': 'material = 1'},
        {'filter2': 'plant = 2'}
       ]
     },
     { id: 2 , name: 'query 2', filters: [
        { 'filter1': 'material = 1'},
        {'filter2': 'plant = 2'}
        ]
     }
  ];

   onChange(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      console.log(this.selected);
  }
}
```

What I would like to have happen is that when the onChange event is called that either I pass the Object value of the selected item into that method or get access to the selected value through the property bound in ngModel.

```
//expected
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value) // selected object bound to ngValue
  console.log(this.selected) // ngModel updated to object bound to selected option 
}
```

But unfortunately, the `event.target.value` is a string version of the object and `this.selected` sort of works but is always behind on being updated.

Is there another way or proper way to handle this? Is the delay in the ngModel a bug?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define select inputs/outputs as following:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
  <option *ngFor="let d of data" [ngValue]="d">
    {{d.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

and then the model is correctly applied to the property. http://plnkr.co/edit/JGgflTY9LvrDDhqqlSGP?p=preview

Notice that the definition of ngModel and ngModelChange should be ordered as is in example :)

Comment: Totally works...Tried it on my app and it didn't work...so played around some more. The issue is the order of ngModel and ngModelChange. `(ngModelChange)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="selected"` does not work. The function `onChange()` will be called prior to the ngModel being updated. This is why I was always seeing it update when I would change it again. Could you update your answer with a note about this then I will give you credit for it. I'm also going to throw an issue in the Angular Repo. If it is not a bug then it definitely needs to be documented somewhere.

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue already. I will add this stackoverflow to the issue.  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3406